# Keep Toolbar at top of UIView when using pushViewController and then popViewController?

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller

Update: Another solution to this problem would be if the Navigation bar at the root level of the navigation controller could be transparent or not shown.  Is there a way to make the Navigation bar at the root level of the navigation controller transparent or not shown?

I have a NIB with a toolbar at the top of my top level UIView and below the toolbar is a tableView.  When I use pushViewController on a navigationController to push another UIViewController onto the navigationController, the toolbar is overwritten by the navigation bar.   When I pop the current view back to the root view, the toolbar cannot be seen as there is a blank bar across the top.  There is now also a gap between the toolbar and the top of the tableView about the size of the toolbar.  So the view looks like from the top: 
1) shaded blank bar, 
2) blank space about the size of a toolbar, 
3) tableview

How can I make the toolbar of the top level NIB appear at the top of the UIView after using popViewController?

In the top level view I instantiate a UINavigationController:

```
 self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ListsController];
```

and then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I push a view controller

```
ItemsController * Items  = [[ItemsController alloc] 
                                         initWithNibName:@"Items" bundle:nil] ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Items animated:YES];
```

To get the initial pushed view to display I do the following:

```
UIView *navView = self.navigationController.view;
CGRect navFrame = navView.frame;
//  navFrame.origin.y -= 20;
navView.frame = navFrame;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow *appWindow = appDelegate.window;


[appWindow addSubview:navView];
```

Any idea how I can get the top level toolbar not to be overwritten when popping back to the top level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make the navigation bar hidden at the root level using:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.table reloadData];
}
```

Then at the next lower level of the navigation stack, make the navigation bar unhidden:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.table reloadData];
}
```